# how to get record from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

if-statement events table is returning null or blank user id then query should get result from lead group table.........any easy way

```
case lgid='' then select 
    select user_id from event where created_timestamp in (select user_id 
    from lead_group  as lgid where created_timestamp in(select event_id 
    from lead where created_timestamp=1450473084))
ELSE
    select user_id from event where created_timestamp in(select event_id 
    from lead where created_timestamp=1450473084)
END
```

Comment: can you explain what you want to do from these queries???

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that :

```
    events table contains event_id and user_id
    lead_group table contains user_id 
    lead table contains event_id and created_timestamp
```

Query :

```
    select e.user_id
    from events e
    join lead_group lg on lg.user_id = e.user_id 
    join lead l on l.event_id = e.event_id and l.created_timestamp =     '1450473084'
```

Comment: thanxs Naveed i have used UNION for this and which was a proper way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve data from two tables, use the JOIN function.[link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)